# How do I redirect to this url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite an url to make a website cms more user friendly. The joomla cms is accessed by /cms/administrator, I just want it to be accessable by /cms

So I added this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^cms/$ /cms/administrator [L]
```

But it doesn't redirect me to cms/administrator. What am I doing wrong?

My entire .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine  on


#Indexes uitzetten
Options -Indexes

#Website

DirectoryIndex index.php

#CMS rewrite
RewriteRule ^cms/$ /cms/administrator [L]

#Rewrites
RewriteRule     ^taarten/(.*).html taartenlisting.php?alias=$1 [L]
RewriteRule     ^taart/(.*).html content.php?alias=$1 [L]
RewriteRule     ^(.*).html artikel.php?alias=$1 [L]
```

Comment: You want rewriting or redirecting if redirecting use `[R,L]` flag also.

Comment: Rewrite actually, if you type in /cms that you end up at /cms/administrator

Comment: What's the point? All the URLs that Joomla creates will still have the full path, right?

Comment: @Walf I just want users to go directly to the login page for the cms, not some weird page where you can see posts made by who and when. Which is where a user ends up now when typing /cms

Comment: [I think your install is in the `cms` sub-directory](https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=740947), so that's not "some weird page", that's the front-end of Joomla. What have you got running in the web root? How are you routing to Joomla content without that folder prefix. I'd probably move the Joomla files into the root and reconfigure it. I have no idea about the exact steps you would take to complete that, nor the best way to update hard-coded or db content links. You could mitigate the consequences od doing so by redirecting to remove the old folder prefix.

Comment: Yeah I could do that, but it's way easier (if I knew how to do it correctly) to just redirect /cms/ to /cms/administrator. And only /cms/ at the end or else /cms/administrator would result in an infinite loop.

Comment: Still don't get how your root dir gets Joomla content when it's set to come from the `cms` sub-directory.

Comment: Your Website and your Joomla back end is allways separated by this administrator directory (this is a real subdirectory). So if your Joomla is installed in /cms than your Administrator area is in /cms/administrator. If you redirect all from /cms to /cms/administrator no one can see your homepage.